# Dynamically populating data into chart in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have few charts ready in `chart.js`. I am trying to put the data that I have fetched through `JSON` file. How do I change the chart data automatically in a chart? I am getting `json` data from `URL`.

```
chartData1:{
            labels: ["01 Jan","02 Jan","03 Jan","04 Jan","05 Jan","06 
                     Jan","07 Jan"],
            datasets: [{
                 label: "s1",
               data: 
         [100,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,1,1,0,1,3,2,1,0],

               fill:false,

                  borderColor: 'Orange',
                  lineTension:0,
                  borderWidth:2,
                  radius:2
              },
               {
                 label: "s2",
                 data: 
             [2,3,4,1,4,5,3,2,0,1,0,3,5,6,3,7,2,0,5,3,1,2,3,1,0,5,4,5,8,6,2],
                fill:false,
                borderColor: 'Violet',
                lineTension:0,
                borderWidth:2,
                radius:2
             }
            ] 
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

"line-chart" is the id of the  `<canvas>` where you want to display chart.

Try with this.

```
var chart1 = document.getElementById("line-chart").getContext("2d");
                      window.myLine = new Chart(chart1).Line(chartData1, {
                      responsive: true,
                      scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.2)",
                      scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
                      scaleFontColor: "#c5c7cc"

                      });
```

Comment: I am getting a json data from a url how to process that data and show them in the chart?